# PHP function checking if you can create an object of a certain type?

Tags: php, function, object

It would take too long to explain why I need this, but I was wondering if there was a PHP function to check if a type of object was recognized.  In other words, a function that would check if

```
$dog = new Dog();
```

would cause an error, because Dog didn't exist.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function called `class_exists`

For further explanation, see the PHP manual page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

See [class_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php). I think it is what you want. OR you can just wrap it with a [try catch block](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Hope this helps.

Comment: A `try-catch`-block will not work as PHP will raise a fatal error when trying to use the variable holding the newly instantiated class. `class_exists` is by far the best option.